# How to send different message to users

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I trying to make bot send different response.

So for example below code when we type `?mention_ping @user` bot reply's `Pong`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mention_ping(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data:
      if(p['ID'] == str(member.id)):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, p)
```

So like this when we type `?mention_ping @user` bot needs to reply from external file like .json.

all members details are saved in external file like .json.
So all response for every member should be different so how to start this.

For more clear example: external file .json will be full of details of all members like name, age, DOB, Phone number  etc...

```
[
    {
        "ID": "01", 
        "Name": "Steve", 
        "Sex": "Male", 
        "age": "30", 
        "DOB": "22-3-2000",
        "PH": "222-333-3333"
    }, 
]
```

Comment: The error you are getting is because `p` is a string.  What exactly does you json file look like?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  as Tristo told i copied his example data.txt file.
"ID": "125125", by replacing `125125` to user id `1234567890`

Comment: I think you used the second example they gave without making the modifications to the provided code that they indicated would be necessary, specifically changing `for p in data` to `for p in data['people']:`

Comment: So that's the `p` dict. You can now retrieve the values from it using the keys to construct your response.  something like `"Hello {Name}, your ID is {ID}".format(**p)`

Comment: Yup working. how to make it work if we have multiple files. Or what i need to add if i need to change `member.id` to just any text like `?mention_ping Steve`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first add `import json`
The code would look something like this

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mention_ping(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data:
      if(p['ID'] == str(member.id)):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, p)
```

where data.txt is

> [{"ID": "01", "Name": "Steve", "Sex": "Male", "age": "30", "DOB":
>   "22-3-2000", "PH": "222-333-3333"}]

*You were missing a comma before "PH" so your json file wouldnt've worked anyway*

For multiple people data.txt would look like :

> {"people":  [
>   {"ID": "123123", "Name": "Steve", "Sex": "Male", "age":
>   "30", "DOB": "22-3-2000", "PH": "222-333-3333"},
>   {"ID": "124124",
>   "Name": "Rachel", "Sex": "Female", "age": "25", "DOB": "22-4-2003", "PH":
>   "222-333-4444"},
>   {"ID": "125125", "Name": "George", "Sex": "Male", "age":
>   "22", "DOB": "21-3-2001", "PH": "222-333-5555"}   ]   }

and the for loop would have to include ['people'] `for p in data['people']:`

Where the 'ID' key is users' discord ID

Comment: I've edited my answer so that now it uses the member you pass through the command (ex. `!ping @user_name`  -> {user_name info}) instead. So basically the value of your "ID" key in the JSON file would be the ID of a certain user (you can get it by right clicking their name and chosing _Copy ID_ )and it would find the user by ID and print all of its data. Using IDs instead of nicknames is better as it's unique for a particular user

Comment: The main thing is that now it works! To mark to anyone in the future reading this with a similar problem you can mark the thread as 'answered' by [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I don't see a reason to have multiple files but if you really want to you can replace the 2nd and 3rd line with `async def ping(ctx, member: discord.Member,file_name= "data.txt"):` and  `with open(file_name) as json_file:`
Then when you call it you do `!mention_ping @user_name file_name.txt` where file_name.txt is an optional argument and if you don't write anything there it will default to "data.txt"